# SystemVerilog: treat don't cares and high impedances like logic low in arithmetic operations

Tags: system-verilog

I am working on SystemVerilog projects in which I need to create many 2+ dimension registers and use them in arithmetic operations, and every time I create a register, I need to manually fill it with zeroes before using them on sequential operation loops where the value assigned to the individual elements of the registers is a function of the value already present in them since the default values in these registers are don't cares.

Is there a (synthesizable) way to treat the don't cares like a logic low in the arithmetic operations so that I can do away with the necessity to manually fill them with zeroes every time?

Comment: how would you determine that  `1` is a `don't care`?

Comment: I do not need to determine if a `1` is a `don't care`. The problem is the effect the don't care terms have on arithmetic. The result of an arithmetic operation with any number of operations being don't care is that the result is always a don't care (at least in simulation), which is what I need to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, what you want to do is not possible. The registers are not initialized to a "don't care" state, they are initially "unknown". It is confusing that the letter X is used to represent both conditions. "Unknown" literally means that the register bits could be zero or one and we don't know which; it is not some distinct third state that could be detected.

You will need to explicitly take some action to load the registers with zeros before you begin your sequential operations. Typically you would add a reset input to your entire design and use that to reset all registers to their desired initial state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was what I was doing and I did not quite understand why I could not use `don't care`s in arithmetic operations. Your answer does clarify my question.